# Kendo menu onSelect, how to determine the last child

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-menu

I'm working with the Kendo UI menu widget, and would like to only trigger the onSelect event when the last child menu item has been selected:

For example, let's say I select "Business Group" menu item below. I then want to trigger additional functions. However, if I click on "Report" I don't want to do anything.

It's probably something easy like checking for last child, but I'm still trying to figure that out.

Here's the HTML code with "kendo-menu" widget:

```
<div class="widget-content text-left text-info" style="float:left; border:none;">
    <div class="widget-content" text-left text-info style="float:left; border:none; width:100px;">
        <span>
            <ul kendo-menu style="display: inline-block"  k-orientation="vm.menuOrientation"
            k-rebind="vm.menuOrientation" k-on-select="vm.onSelect(kendoEvent)" k-closeOnClick="false">
                <li>
                Reports
                    <ul>
                        <li>VaR
                            <ul>
                                <li>Business Group</li>
                                <li>Stress Scenarios</li>
                                <li>IR Risk - PV10</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>Ctrpty
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="../index.html#/dashboard">Industry</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="index.html#/dashboard?repttype='MTM'">MTM</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </div>
```

In my javascript controller code, I wire up the event:

```
vm.onSelect = function (ev) {          
      changeReportType(ev);
    };
```

However it fires every time I click any of the menu items. I'd like to react on the bottom most item only.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply search for `ul` descendants:

```
vm.onSelect = function (e) {          
    var isLeaf = $(e.item).find("ul").length === 0;

    if (isLeaf) changeReportType(ev);
};
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/TZwK5/4/))

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using .className.match() which worked well:

```
function swapGrid(e) {                    
        if (!e.item.className.match("selectable")) {
            // we have not yet reached the last child (i.e. the one with the "selectable" class).
            return;
        }
        var reptType = e.item.firstChild.textContent;    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont know how you generate your markup but you could add class selector for those which can be clicked.

JavaScript:

```
vm.onSelect = function (ev) {          
  var item = $(ev);
  if ( item.hasClass("selectable") ) {
      changeReportType(ev);
  } else {
      ev.preventDefault();
  }
};
```

Markup:

```
<li class="selectable">Business Group</li>
```

Comment: great I'll try it this morning. I ended up using {if (e.item.firstChild.text == e.item.firstChild.text)}, which in this case means I have reached the bottom. But my code doesn't seem like a clean solution.

Comment: for some reason the item.hasClass("selectable") always evaluates to FALSE.